# How to treat a class, parameters

Tags: python, oop

I want to know that how many parameters I can put in a class, is there any limit or if there a more handsome way for putting attributes.have a look at the code and guide me

```
class residential():
    def __init__(self,type,capacity,location,parking,mosque,waterbackup,cctvsecure):
```

Comment: The duplicate target doesn't seem to match. It would be worth pointing that the 255 arguments limit was removed in Python 3.7 and that dataclasses allows to omit the `__init__` function of a class with multiple arguments. I think the question is valid.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you mean how many parameters can a function or method be defined as accepting, or do you mean how many attributes can a class have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number of arguments for any function in Python used to be 255. Since Python 3.7, this limit has been removed.

Another novelty in Python 3.7 is the new module [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) which simplifies the declaration of a class with multiple arguments.

> For example this code:
>
> ```
> @dataclass
> class InventoryItem:
>     '''Class for keeping track of an item in inventory.'''
>     name: str
>     unit_price: float
>     quantity_on_hand: int = 0
>
>     def total_cost(self) -> float:
>         return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
> ```
>
> Will add, among other things, a `__init__()` that looks like:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, name: str, unit_price: float, quantity_on_hand: int=0):
>     self.name = name
>     self.unit_price = unit_price
>     self.quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand
> ```